# Bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to create a model in pytorch, but I can't 
compute the loss. 
It's always return **Bool value of Tensor with more 
than one value is ambiguous**
Actually, I run example code, it work.

```
loss = CrossEntropyLoss()
input = torch.randn(8, 5)
input
target = torch.empty(8,dtype=torch.long).random_(5)
target
output = loss(input, target)
```

Here is my code,

```
################################################################################
##
##
import torch
from torch.nn import Conv2d, MaxPool2d, Linear, CrossEntropyLoss, MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss
from torch.nn.functional import relu, conv2d, max_pool2d, linear, softmax
from torch.optim import adadelta
##
##
##  Train
Train = {}
Train["Image"]    = torch.rand(2000, 3, 76, 76)
Train["Variable"] = torch.rand(2000, 6)
Train["Label"] = torch.empty(2000, dtype=torch.long).random_(2)
##
##
##  Valid
Valid = {}
Valid["Image"]    = torch.rand(150, 3, 76, 76)
Valid["Variable"] = torch.rand(150, 6)
Valid["Label"]    = torch.empty(150, dtype=torch.long).random_(2)
################################################################################
##
##
##  Model
ImageTerm    = Train["Image"]
VariableTerm = Train["Variable"]
Pip = Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1, padding=0)(ImageTerm)
Pip = MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2), stride=None, padding=0)(Pip)
Pip = Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1, padding=0)(Pip)
Pip = MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2), stride=None, padding=0)(Pip)
Pip = Pip.view(2000, -1)
Pip = torch.cat([Pip, VariableTerm], 1)
Pip = Linear(in_features=18502, out_features=1000 , bias=True)(Pip)
Pip = Linear(in_features=1000, out_features=2 , bias=True)(Pip)
##
##
##  Loss
Loss = CrossEntropyLoss(Pip, Train["Label"])
```

The error is on  **Loss = CrossEntropyLoss(Pip, Train["Label"])**,
thanks.

Comment: related posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946920/bool-value-of-tensor-with-more-than-one-value-is-ambiguous-in-pytorch
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-bool-value-of-variable-objects-containing-non-empty-torch-longtensor-is-ambiguous/7310
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-bool-value-of-tensor-with-more-than-one-value-is-ambiguous/43800
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-cant-one-pass-data-through-a-torch-relu-module-directly

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In your minimal example, you create an object "loss" of the class "CrossEntropyLoss". This object is able to compute your loss as

```
loss(input, target)
```

However, in your actual code, you try to create the object "Loss", while passing Pip and the labels to the "CrossEntropyLoss" class constructor.
Instead, try the following:

```
loss = CrossEntropyLoss()
loss(Pip, Train["Label"])
```

**Edit (explanation of the error message):** The error Message `Bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous` appears when you try to cast a tensor into a bool value. This happens most commonly when passing the tensor to an **if** condition, e.g.

```
input = torch.randn(8, 5)
if input:
    some_code()
```

The second argument of the `CrossEntropyLoss` class constructor expects a boolean. Thus, in the line

```
Loss = CrossEntropyLoss(Pip, Train["Label"])
```

the constructor will at some point try to use the passed tensor `Train["Label"]` as a boolean, which throws the mentioned error message.

Comment: it would be nice if you reference somewhere what that error actually means

Answer (score 27):

You can not use the class `CrossEntropyLoss` directly. You should instantiate this class before using it.

original code:

```
loss = CrossEntropyLoss(Pip, Train["Label"])
```

should be replaced by:

```
loss = CrossEntropyLoss()
loss(Pip, Train["Label"])
```

Answer (score 13):

First Instantiate loss

```
L = CrossEntropyLoss()
```

Then compute loss

```
L(y_pred, y_true)
```

This will fix the error.

Comment: Worked for a binary classifier I was making with using LSTMS and Linear layers. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

if you landed up in this page because of pyplot not displaying your tensor image properly then use `plt.imshow()` instead of `plt.show()`

for example, instead of

```
plt.show(images[0].permute(1,2,0))
```

use

```
plt.imshow(images[0].permute(1,2,0))
```