# remove torch tensor from a list raises RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous

Tags: list, torch

I want to move an element from the training list to the validation list. Without torch tensors the method works, as in the following example:

```
test = [[2,1],[3,2],[4,4],[5,67]]
element = test[2]
test.remove(element)
print(test)


Out: [[2, 1], [3, 2], [5, 67]]
```

My question now is why it doesn't work when I do it from `train_data` to `validation_data` with a list of tensors? And is there a way to make it work?
I eventually could do it before converting to tensors, but I prefer afterward.

One element, which I got from the `train_data` has the dimension: `1 64 3 1080 1920`

The error I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22400/338233821.py in <module>
     18     validation_data.append(element)
     19     print(len(validation_data), len(validation_data[0]), len(validation_data[0][0]), len(validation_data[0][0][0]), len(validation_data[0][0][0][0]))
---> 20     train_data.remove(element)
     21 

RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946920/bool-value-of-tensor-with-more-than-one-value-is-ambiguous-in-pytorch) I know that somewhere the tensor is casted into a boolean, but where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that using `train_data.pop(index)` works. But it's still not clear to me why `.remove()` doesn't work. I assume there is somewhere an if case in the `.remove()` function which triggers the error.