# Why I'm getting error: "Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous"

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
l = torch.tensor([0, 1, 1, 1], requires_grad=False)
r = torch.rand(4, 2)

torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(r, l)
```

And I'm getting error:

```
RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

I looked here: [Bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous in Pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946920/bool-value-of-tensor-with-more-than-one-value-is-ambiguous-in-pytorch) but didn't understand the answers.

What do I need to change in order to run the code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object you are manipulating, `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`, is a PyTorch module class, not a function.

Therefore, you should either intialize it beforehand:

```
>>> ce_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
>>> cel_loss(r, l)
```

Or use the functional interface, *i.e.* [`torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy.html):

```
>>> F.cross_entropy(r, l)
```